# How do i get Milliseconds in GMT?

Tags: java

```
    YhTimestamp timestamp = new YhTimestamp();
    System.out.println(timestamp.getTime());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println(time);
```

You will get always timestamp in GMT either you use Calendar or Date or System.getCurrenttimemills()

Comment: You will get always timestamp in GMT either you use Calendar.getInstence() or new Date().getTime() or System.getCurrenttimemills()

Comment: A millisecond is always relative to the Unix epoch, by convention. So every millisecond timestamp is "in UTC / GMT".

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a little bit. Do you mean that you want to see the milliseconds when **printing out** the timestamp? You can edit your question to add such additional information.